# .htaccess rewrite multiple domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a project that lives at the following domain:

```
http://www.example.com/PROJECT/
```

within project, there are three subpages, which have pages structured like this:

```
http://www.example.com/PROJECT/first-subpage.php?Page_ID=12345 
http://www.example.com/PROJECT/second-subpage.php?Page_ID=12345
http://www.example.com/PROJECT/third-subpage.php?Page_ID=12345
```

I am trying to write multiple Mod Rewrite rules for each of these, so that I can have-urls of the following style redirect like so:

```
http://www.example.com/PROJECT/first-section/12345/some-other-text-here
>>
http://www.example.com/PROJECT/first-subpage.php?Page_ID=12345
```

Here is what I have, but I have not been able to get the matches to get picked up, according to this [.htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

here is my current `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /PROJECT/

<filesMatch "^(/first-section/.*)">
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$/(.*)$/(.*)$ /first-subpage.php?page_ID=$2
</filesMatch>

<filesMatch "^(/second-section/.*)">
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$/(.*)$/(.*)$ /second-subpage.php?page_ID=$2
</filesMatch>

<filesMatch "^(/third-section/.*)">
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$/(.*)$/(.*)$ /third-subpage.php?page_ID=$2
</filesMatch>
```

how can I get these rules to match the urls properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^PROJECT/first-section/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /PROJECT/first-subpage.php?Page_ID=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^PROJECT/second-section/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /PROJECT/second-subpage.php?Page_ID=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^PROJECT/third-section/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /PROJECT/third-subpage.php?Page_ID=$1 [NC]
```

Note : Please double check the var name as it's case sensitive , your variable in the question was `Page_ID` , and it's `page_ID` in your `.htaccess` code .

Comment: If your htaccess in located in the /PROJECT/ folder, then remove `PROJECT/` (only the ones after `^`)